# How to change fill of svg which is linked using <object> tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an **HTML file** in which I have linked an svg object:

`<object id="svgGlasses" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/glasses.svg"></object>`

and **glasses.svg** as follows

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="42.604px" height="42.604px" viewBox="0 0 42.604 42.604" style="enable-background:new 0 0 42.604 42.604;"
 xml:space="preserve"> 
    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
        .circle{fill:#FAED24;}
    ]]>
    </style>
    <g id="Circle">
        <circle id="svgInternalID" class="circle" cx="21.302" cy="21.302" r="19.802"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

When the user clicks on a button, which is in the HTML somewhere, I want the color of the circle to change to black.

I researched and found this JS, which I also added to the HTML, but it didn't work

```
var Head= document.getElementById("svgGlasses").contentDocument();
Head = Head.getElementById("svgInternalID");
Head.style.setProperty("fill","color", "#ff0000");
```

Is there any way to do it without using inline svg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do it without inline SVG and you're pretty close to the right answer already.

You've the arguments in the wrong place for setProperty. This works for me:

```
var Head= document.getElementById("svgGlasses").contentDocument();
Head = Head.getElementById("svgInternalID");
Head.style.setProperty("fill","#000000", "");
```

The colour you want to set should be the second argument.

Comment: It did for me when I tested it. What UA are you trying this on?

Comment: I was using Firefox when I tested the above solution.