# Processing SVG and fill in specific area

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an app, and want my users to be able to upload their images and then have the ability to colorize certain objects in it.

Example:  1.  https://www.visualizecolor.com/glidden#/StockPhoto?projectid=f1c432bd-8e17-45b0-93a0-acef22f48d2d
          2. https://www.sherwin-williams.com/visualizer#/active

I've tried this solution [change particular area of an image and fill color in that area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716217/change-particular-area-of-an-image-and-fill-color-in-that-area) but again I don't know how to adjust the SVG paths when the user uploads a new photo.

Answer (score 0):

Svg Image can be set to the `<image>` src attribute but to make svg editable like to change color you have to make `<object>` tag and set source in the `data` attribute

and after that color can be edited by using

```
<object class="svgClass" type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg"></object>

    document.querySelector(".svgClass").getSVGDocument().getElementById("svgInternalID").setAttribute("fill", "red")
```

[How to change fill of svg which is linked using <object> tag in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678168/how-to-change-fill-of-svg-which-is-linked-using-object-tag-in-html)

[Changing SVG image color with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872947/changing-svg-image-color-with-javascript)